# Can I capture a param but avoid showing it in the url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to capture the id of an element that is clicked on and then pass that id to the controller, all without showing the id in either the link or the url param, and without having to write custom ajax loading. Anything like that available in rails out of the box?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly what you're trying to do, but sounds like a regular `POST` should do it? I think you'll need to show your code to get help beyond that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to achieve (what's the end goal)? It sounds like you want to communicate between the client and server without using ajax or encoding params in the user's url.

The usual ways of doing that, with those constraints, would be:

1) Wrap the click target in a form, and set the id to a hidden value. On click, just post the form. This will require a page refresh, but since it's a POST, won't muck up the url.

2) Set the id in a cookie, force a page refresh, read the id on the server and unset it. This will obviously also require a page refresh, but won't encode anything in the url.

3) Use an invisible iFrame to load a url with the param of interest. This won't require a refresh and the url can be anything, since the user will never see it.

If a page refresh/change is fine, the form route is probably best. If you don't want the page to refresh though, an xhr request is clearly the best solution. It's *really* simple to do, but an iFrame solution would be a hack that probably meets your needs too.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you don't want to show the ID to the user but you need the element ID to hit the server.

You could use a custom request header, but that would require an AJAX approach. Here's a sketch with JQuery

```
$("a.sends_element_id").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
     url: $(e.target).attr("href"),
     type: "GET",
     beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Element-ID', $(e.target).attr("id");},
     success: function(result) { 
       // Do something here to display the page
       // Eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page
     }
  });
```

Comment: You got the question right. This is probably the best solution, but still not ideal. At this stage I do actually need the page to reload to the next page and to respond to the controller actions of the next page. Doing everything through ajax would require that I update a whole slew of other things, which won't be possible atm. Any other ideas?

Comment: Sounds like a cookie via an AJAX is your best bet in that case.

Comment: ^ YES! ... so simply, so brilliant. Thank you.